# Remote desktop credentials not working on either pc

Tags: remote-desktop

Whenever i try to logon to the remote desktop.
It keeps saying the credentials are incorrect, on both devices, this is really doing my head in and i cant find a fix.
Im using the correct name and password, and the pcs are able to ping to one another, ive tried both the hostname and ip, didnt work on either pc.

it keeps saying the logon attempt failed
i have already tried the secpol.msc and services.msc method

Comment: Have you checked the logs? What do they say? https://www.anyviewer.com/how-to/windows-server-connection-logs-2578.html

Comment: i tried doing the filtering and putting the ID to 1149 but no results showed up

Answer (score 0):

You don' give us much information to go on.

But a couple of general troubleshooting steps come to mind:

- Is Remote Desktop enabled on the target devices? The function is not ON by default in Windows.
- Are the user-accounts that you attempt to use for login authorized for Remote Desktop login on the target devices? By default ONLY Administrators can login to remote desktop and users that are a member of the 'Remote Desktop Users" group (by default that group is empty).
- Last but not least. If this is an environment without Active Directory you have to bear in mind that each computer does it's own user-management and has no knowledge of accounts existing on the other computers.
  User "Jake" on computer "A" is not the same user as user "Jake" on
  computer "B" even though they may have the same password.
  When logging in from computer A to computer B Jake will have to explicitly
  tell computer B that he wants to login with his B credentials so he
  needs to prefix the username with the computer-name (like "B\Jake"). If he just enters "Jake" his own computer (A) will supply the "A\Jake" account, because it has no idea that "B\Jake" exists too.)

Comment: yes remote desktop is enabled on both devices, huh i didnt know that, i read it before and enabled it but didnt know you needed to add the user aswell, so do i just add the user or do i do "pc name"/"username"?

Comment: just tried doing the last 2 solutions but they both didnt work for me either

Answer (score 0):

If you have wrong credentials being used, you could try to remove them
as follows :

- Run *Start > Credential Manager*
- Check both Web Credentials and Windows Credentials
- In each, check if you see related credentials
- Remove a credential by clicking in the drop-down arrow and then "Remove".

If this succeeds, you will need to enter again the right credentials
when connecting.

Answer (score 0):

Too many attempts? Exist a rule to freeze connection if for "X" number of times
you write wrong password etc... and exist registry or local security policy to fix... if the problem is this.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).